# Toggle HPC Jobs

Tags: bash, shell, slurm, hpc

I'm trying to find a covenient way to peek through the jobs I have submited on an HPC system. Currently, I have the function

```sh
peek() {ccc_mpeek "$1" | less;}
```

defined in my `.bashrc`, where `ccc_mpeek` is an HPC specific function to see the output file of a running job and the `$1` argument is the JOBID.

However, this is still a little incovenient, since I have to manually copy and paste the JOBID (7 digits) when I want to run the function above.

I'm looking for a way in which I can **toggle through JOBID's** as the argument to the previous function, based on the output of the `squeue -u user_name`, which has the following header:

```
         JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `squeue` command has an option to choose the information that is displayed. In you case, you would run

```
squeue -h -t R --me -o %i
```

to remove the header (`-h`) , filter only "running" jobs (`-t R`) and only display the job ID (`-o %i`).

Assuming you have only one job running, you can then define

```
peek() {ccc_mpeek "$(squeue -t R --me -o %i)" | less;}
```

If you have multiple jobs running, you will need to adapt it to either show only the first job ( `... | head -1`) or iterate through the jobs with a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added `squeue -h ... | head -$1 | tail -1` to your solution to get the _n-th_ line of IDs in queue.

Comment: Great. Another option would be to assign names to your jobs (`#SBATCH --job-name`) and then use that to reference them `squeue -n "$1" --me -o %i`.